# How to render a pixel array most efficiently to a window in c++?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, sdl, pixel

So far i have been using SDL 2.0, copy my pixel array into a texture which then gets rendered on the screen.
My render method looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH*HEIGHT; i++){
        pixels[i] = 0xFFFF0000;
        //pixel Format: AARRGGBB
    }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(sdlTexture, NULL, pixels, 800 * sizeof(Uint32));

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, sdlTexture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

I then measured the time it takes to render it once in nanoseconds (via chrono) and compared it to a similar way of rendering pixels in java:
(the pixel array stores the pixels of the "displayImage")

```
BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    screen.clear()
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH*HEIGHT; i++){
        pixels[i] = 0xFF0000;
        //pixel Format: RRGGBB
    }
    Graphics2D g =  (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(displayImage,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);



    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
```

Surprisingly i then saw that it takes about 600.000 nanoseconds to render it in Java and about 2.000.000 nanoseconds to render it in C++.

So my question is if theres a more efficient way to draw a pixel array like i've got on the screen since (i'm assuming) C++ should render it faster than Java.

Also this is how i measured the time:
C++:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

//render function

auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto result = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Java:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

//render function

long end = System.nanoTime();
long result = end - start;
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: How many textures are you drawing? With vsync enabled 2.000.000 nanoseconds is still less than a single frame.

Comment: I'm only initializing one texture which i'm drawing on.
What i posted is basically my whole render function, since i'm just using it to test the performance right now.

Comment: First, in the C++, you clear the screen, but in java you don't.

Comment: Changed it now and tried it out but it doesn't really affect the speed.

Comment: Feels like you are measuring some sort of "debug" build of C++.

Comment: If i'm using the release version i get 1.000.000 or 1.000.100.
Is that an okay processing time for a 2D game?
Or is there an even faster way of rendering?

Comment: 1ms is ok for anything, you only need <16ms to get 60fps. Though you may want to use hardware acceleration if you are above 10ms. Another guess about the difference : In C++, are you using triple buffering like in java ? Some buffering modes can slow down rendering. Also, if you draw on the whole screen, you don't need to clear before.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to activate double/triplebuffering in SDL 2 any ideas?

Comment: I never used SDL but if I'm not mistaken, creating your window with `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` and your renderer with `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` should enable decent double buffering, and adding `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` for the renderer should enable triple buffering.

Comment: Doesn't Vsync just sync the framerate?

Comment: Triple buffering and vsync aren't exactly related, but usually (althought not required) vsync needs triple buffering so the software can start drawing another frame while a complete frame is waiting for the vsync signal. So in most cases vsync = triple buffering. And contrary to popular belief, vsync in itself doesn't affect the framerate. It only does if your software wait on vsync. I didn't try, but if `SDL_RenderPresent` wait for vsync, then it will indeed sync the framerate.

Comment: Alright i see thanks so its alright if i leave my rendering system like that?

Comment: It still kinda bugs me that the C++ version is slower than the Java one.

Comment: Leaving it like that is probably not a problem. It's hard to tell what the underlying APIs are using, so my guess was that using the flags I suggested might improve the performance for the C++. Also, I found that some compilers enable massive optimizations on loops when the array (`pixels` for you) is a `unique_ptr`, though you won't gain much if the loop wasn't slow in the first place.

Comment: Any idea how i can pass the `unique_ptr` into the "updateTexture" function?

Comment: Use `.get()`. Note that using `unique_ptr` might not gain anything (though sometime it did improve performances for me). Maybe you can post a small working code so I can check for potential performances improvement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70057/discussion-between-styxs-and-elderbug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be noted that measuring a time so short isn't always reliable, so the values should be taken with a grain of salt. Even if java and C++ use the same system timer, there might be unrelated differences.

Regarding the code, `SDL_UpdateTexture` will issue a copy to the internal buffer, and is therefore a bit slow. You should use `SDL_LockTexture` and `SDL_UnlockTexture` instead. This will allow a direct access to the internal buffer.

Also, you don't need to clear the screen in your case because your texture spans the whole screen, and therefore overwrite everything.

If you need to fill the screen, of just a line, you can use the assembly instruction `rep stos`, which is much faster than a loop. With Visual C++, you can emit `rep stos` for uint32 using `__stosd`. This works like `memset`, but for uint32 (you also have the uint16 version with `__stosw`, and uint64 with `__stosq`, x64 only). There is the equivalent `__movsd` to make a copy, but well implemented `memcpy` can be even faster.